# Parameterize CosmosDB query with IN clause

Tags: azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm looking for any working way to parameterize IN clause in query.
I have tried something like this, But not working.

```
{      
    query: "Select r.id, r.Shipper.Name AS Shipper FROM root r WHERE r.Shipper.Name IN (@Shipper0, 
                 Shipper1)",     
    parameters: [          
        { name: "@Shipper0", value: "ABC" },
        { name: "@Shipper1", value: "XYZ" }     
    ] 
}
```

To create this `"(@Shipper0, @Shipper1)"`, did some c# coding.
Without params same query working fine.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
```

Working query: ==>

```
$"Select r.id, r.Shipper.Name AS Shipper FROM root r Where r.Shipper.Name IN ( '{string.Join("', '", list)}')";
```

Thanks "IN" advance.

Comment: I think this is SDK bug, I have reported https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-dotnet/issues/614